# Windows CurDir function - what is its low level declaration and is there a Unicode version?

Tags: windows, path, filesystems, relative-path

For a REAL Studio program I need to inquire a specific drive letter's *current directory*, as it occurs in a path like this:

```
d:filename
```

Note that it's a relative path on D: here.

There is a GetCurrentDirectory function, but that doesn't let me specify the D drive, so it's of no use here.

I found the CurDir function, which is what I need functionally, but I can't find any info on the MSDN site about the DLL it lives in, nor it exported name in that DLL.

I've tried the names CurDir and CurDirA, and the DDL names user32.dll and win32.dll and kernel32.dll.

Also, it appears the CurDir function as provided to VB returns a ASCII, not a Unicode, string. Is there a Unicode version, e.g. "CurDirW"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't maintain separate current directories for separate drives. That's something that DOS used to do and cmd.exe emulates by remembering values for each drive. When you change drive in cmd.exe it sets the current directory, including the drive. If you want the same functionality you'll have to do it yourself.

Raymond Chen blogged about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx

Comment: I _do_ want to support cmd.exe, though. i.e, my utility app shall be able to find the full path if cmd.exe passes something like d:filename - hmm, or may testing setup was wrong and cmd.exe would give the resolved path. i have to double check...

Comment: you'd have to reverse engineer the way cmd keeps track of things. Read Raymond's article. It mentions special environment variables but that was in the context of batch script execution. You may not be able to get hold of that information.

Comment: by the way, although the answer may be inconvenient to you, it nevertheless is the answer to your question.

Comment: If cmd.exe is going to call your app and pass d:filename, even though he current working directory is on a different drive, then I suspect that cmd.exe will automatically expand the path for you. If it didn't then it would be hard to work with console apps that weren't interpreted inside the cmd shell. If it doesn't do this then your only real hope is that some magic environment variables will be available to come to your rescue!

Comment: I just tested this again: No, cmd.exe does NOT expand the path. If I call a tool with z:file, then that's exactly what gets passed to the app, no expansion takes place. Which means that if cmd.exe doesn't reveal his current dir to the app, then something is amiss. Also, there IS CurDir, so what's up with that? Until this has been clarified, I can't accept your answer, because it would suggest a design problem in Windows, and I don't believe in that, not with a feature that's been around since the dawn of DOS

Comment: Alright - the secret lies in the Env - there I can get the values I was looking for, e.g. "=D:" contains cmd.exe's current path for D. That clarifies it. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas `CurDir` is a VB function. If cmd doesn't expand the path then I recommend you enumerate the environment variables and see if you can find it in there!